# How can I union 2 multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 multidimensional arrays. I need the union of these arrays.
Maybe there is a PHP array function to do this. I tried different ways with `array_replace()`, `array_merge()` but I couldn't figure it out. The length array are not fixed. The 2 arrays are:

```
$a = array(
  array(
    'division'=> 'Dhaka',
    'A'=> 0,
    'B'=> 0,
    'C'=> 0,
    'D'=> 0
  ),
  array(
    'division'=> 'Chittagong',
    'A'=> 0,
    'B'=> 0,
    'C'=> 0,
    'D'=> 0
  ),
  array(
    'division'=> 'Rajshahi',
    'A'=> 0,
    'B'=> 0,
    'C'=> 0,
    'D'=> 0
  ),
  array(
    'division'=> 'Mymensingh',
    'A'=> 0,
    'B'=> 0,
    'C'=> 0,
    'D'=> 0
  )
);
$b = array(
  array("division"=> "Dhaka", "A"=> 5, "B"=> 8),
  array("division"=> "Rajshahi", "A"=> 10, "C"=> 2)
);
```

The result should be:

```
$a = array(
      array(
        'division'=> 'Dhaka',
        'A'=> 5, //after union
        'B'=> 8, //after union
        'C'=> 0,
        'D'=> 0
      ),
      array(
        'division'=> 'Chittagong',
        'A'=> 0,
        'B'=> 0,
        'C'=> 0,
        'D'=> 0
      ),
      array(
        'division'=> 'Rajshahi',
        'A'=> 10, //after union
        'B'=> 0, //after union
        'C'=> 2,
        'D'=> 0
      ),
      array(
        'division'=> 'Mymensingh',
        'A'=> 0,
        'B'=> 0,
        'C'=> 0,
        'D'=> 0
      )
    );
```

Comment: What if the sub-arrays in `$a` have values?  Do the values in `$b` always take precedence?  Or do we leave any non-zero values in `$a`?

Comment: have you tried `$a = array_replace_recursive($a, $b);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a multi-dimensional array, you need to replace recursively; but you also need identical string indexes.  If `division` is unique then use that:

```
$a = array_replace_recursive(array_column($a, null, 'division'),
                             array_column($b, null, 'division'));
```

If you want to get back to integer indexes then:

```
$a = array_values(array_replace_recursive(array_column($a, null, 'division'),
                                          array_column($b, null, 'division')));
```